# Does Azure record a script when disabling apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way that I can get the script that Azure runs when disabling logic apps ?

So for example when I click on the disable button , does Azure log away the script behind the procedure that I can use to run form other apps ?

Comment: Something like https://notetoself.tech/2018/01/10/enable-disable-all-logic-apps-in-a-resource-group/

Comment: Yep worked as per the link. It was the formatting of my powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PowerShell command [Set-AzureRmLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.logicapp/set-azurermlogicapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

e.g.

```
Set-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "LogicApp17" -State "Disabled"
```